# How can I unit test mith Mockito my Filter that change Character response and request encoding?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, filter, mockito

I have filter that sets character encoding.How can I test It with Mockito?

My Filter:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "CharacterEncodingFilter")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: at least you should make clear for yourself, what you want to test. The invocation? The call to the other filters in the chain? having the charactoer encoding set to request and response? Depending on that, you mock the objects like request and check, if for instance the setter is called

Comment: you might want to look for Integration testing or provide more details, what you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you are doing a unit test you simply do the following:

```
@Test 
public void filterSetsCharacterEncoding() {
  //given
  CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

  ServletRequest request = mock(ServletRequest.class);
  ServletResponse response = mock(ServletRequest.class);
  FilterChain chain = mock(FilterChain.class);

  //when
  filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

  //then
  verify(request).setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  verify(response).setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}
```

Basically just instantiate the filter, pass mock objects as parameters and verify that the request and response setCharacterEncoding have been called with UTF-8 parameter.

You might also want to verify that chain.doFilter was invoked. I would test that in a new method, as the above method already tests that character encoding was set.